# recover data after repartitioning of disk

Tags: fat32

I have a 40GB hard disk in my desktop PC.
Previously it had two partitions ( C = 20GB FAT32, D = 20GB FAT32 )

I needed to install Fedora 14, so i removed above partitions (without making backup),
and installed Fedora 14 ( with / = 37GB ext4 and swap = 3GB ).

Now I want to recover my data that was stored on D drive.

Is there any chance to recover that data,
if yes, can somebody guide me.

Regards.

Comment: How to close this post?

Answer (score 1):

If you run a full disk scan with R-Studio, you can likely retrieve some or all of the lost files. I have had fairly good success with this. The downside: R-Studio is not free. $50 for home use.

Comment: +1. R-Studio may not be free, but it is worth the price.

Answer (score 0):

I could have sworn i had answered this question before, but here goes.

The good news is that formats don't always completely delete data, and there's a fairly decent chance of drive recovery, as long as your shiny new file system didn't write over the parts of the drive that had data previously.

First, backup your fedora partition with an offline back-up tool, or better yet, some varient of DD, if there's anything there that you need.

Second, give [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) a shot - if it can see your 'old' partition when it analyses it, you may be able to effectively roll back the reformat. You will need to do this off a dos floppy or linux live cd of some sort, as opposed to your install of fedora.